# itunes and ipod music files corrupted

Tags: itunes, ipod

I synchronised my ipod with PC as normal and now have a strange problem – lots of the songs on my ipod are now labelled incorrectly, ie. if I select a Rihanna song and press play it plays another song.   I opened itunes and clicked on the Rihanna song to play and it played another song and the Rihanna song then disappeared from itunes. It is still in my library so I have to go in and open it again so it appears in itunes – going through my ipod there are numerous instances of this – its driving me crazy! I’ve never had this happen before and can’t find anything online anywhere.  I’ve tried synchronising again but the songs are still messed up.  I’ve removed cloud from my iphone but don’t think that was the problem.  Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: *I opened itunes and clicked on the Rihanna song to play and it played another song * ... Personally, I'd just be grateful! Any way, depending on how many songs it's done it too, right click on a song and click on Get Info.

Comment: What OS are you using?  and what version of iTunes?

Answer (score 0):

After searching online, there is 1 suggestion which keeps coming up, which I will just copy verbatim. [Source](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/messed-up-song-names.226507/)

> 1) iTunes Edit menu->Preferences->Advanced, and put checkmarks in the
>   boxes for "Keep iTunes Media folder organized" and "Copy files to
>   iTunes Media folder when adding to library"; save prefs. (If you're
>   using a Mac, it's the iTunes menu->Preferences->Advanced)
>
> 2) iTunes File menu->Library->Organize library; in the box that opens
>   up, put a checkmark in the "Consolidate files" box. If there's a box
>   labelled "Upgrade to iTunes Media organization" make sure it's
>   unchecked. Click the OK button. This should force iTunes to update the
>   file names and folder structure. It works fine for me -- I just tested
>   it with a small library I created and set up to mimic your situation.
>   (Consolidating is normally used to move files from one folder to
>   another without losing iTunes' links to the filepaths. But in this
>   case -- when the music files are already in the desired folder --
>   we're using Consolidation to force iTunes to rename the files that are
>   already there.)

There are also many posts on the [Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3677418?start=0&tstart=0) complaining about this (with no answer in this case).